# Add webform answers

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a likert on a webform with the options *strongly agree*, *disagree*, *neutral*, *agree*, and *disagree*. I want to assign each option a weight, then multiply the number of users responses in each particular category. I haven't found any module currently available for Drupal 8 that does this.

How can I hard code this into the webform submission, and what language would I have to use? I am completely new in Drupal with a background in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to create a custom element and/or alter the submission using a custom PHP module.

I recommend checking out [Webform Analysis](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_analysis) module